# Turn off git path resolution in commit message

Tags: git, relative-path, commit-message

When I use path specs in git commit message, they are resolved in system absolute paths!

E.g.

`git commit -m "/tools/controller subproject moved to submodule"`

will result in

`C:/Program Files/Git/tools/controller subproject moved to submodule`

**How can I turn off this 'feature'?**

My git version is `2.12.0.windows.1`.

Comment: Try single instead of double quotes. Or just `git commit` and add the message via vim.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Thanks a lot! It works for me!

Comment: This seems like a bug in Git Bash; I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1211) for it.

Comment: If you start a path with a `/`, **is** it a relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this is currently a [known issue in Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/7e6648d4734ab12c0f96414bf7667af1efb53cc4/ReleaseNotes.md#known-issues) ([issue tracker link](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1211)). The workaround is to use `MSYS_NO_CONV`:

> If you specify command-line options starting with a slash, POSIX-to-Windows path conversion will kick in converting e.g. "`/usr/bin/bash.exe`" to "`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`". When that is not desired -- e.g. "`--upload-pack=/opt/git/bin/git-upload-pack`" or "`-L/regex/`" -- you need to set the environment variable `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV` temporarily, like so:
>
> `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 git blame -L/pathconv/ msys2_path_conv.cc`
>
> Alternatively, you can double the first slash to avoid POSIX-to-Windows path conversion, e.g. "`//usr/bin/bash.exe`".